# Opencv - Active contours

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I am trying to use the active contour algorithm using OpenCV function. There is an implementation named `cvSnakeImage`. But I can't find an example in the OpenCV documentation. I found an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/555524/answer.aspx). I added some lines and I expect that this code segments the image but the result is not expected. The points from snake method don't move.

I edited a function from this code. And it is here :

```
void AactiveSnake(IplImage* image)
{

points = (CvPoint*)cvAlloc(15*sizeof(CvPoint*));
int x,y;
for(int i = 0;i < 14 ; i++){    
    x = Xvalues[i];
    y = Yvalues[i];
    points[i].x = x;
    points[i].y = y;
}
cout << "AactiveSnake";
cvSnakeImage(image,points,15,&Alfa,&Beta,&Gamma,CV_VALUE,win,criteria,0);

IplImage* temp;
temp = cvCloneImage(imageRGB);
for(int i = 0;i < 14 ; i++){    
    x = points[i].x;
    y = points[i].y;
    Xvalues[i] = x;
    Yvalues[i] = y;
    cvCircle(temp,cvPoint(x,y),1,CV_RGB(255,0,0),-1);       
}
cout << "*\n";
cvShowImage( "Snake-Points", temp );
waitKey(0);

}
```

Input image :

[image]

Comment: This code works. I select 14 points, but 15 points are wanted. If you run the code with 15 selected points, it works fine. I don't delete this question to guide for snake implementation.

Comment: just ty to avoid opencv's legacy code. it also got removed in 3.0

Comment: ok, @berak. But I cannot find any function is equal to snakeImage. Am I wrong?

Comment: no, unfortunately you're right. at least try to stay away from IplImages, deprecated c-api stuff in the *rest* of your code.